# Move to next form control from another class C#

Tags: c#, forms, controls

Is there any way to call `processTabKey();` from MyClass.cs which has helpers, and use it for each form that calls it, instead of making one method on each form?

For example `Form1.cs` calls `myMethod()` from `MyClass.cs` which contains `processTabKey();` and then move to next control on `Form1.cs` ?

Thanks in advice.
**MyClass.cs**

```
public static void TextBoxKeyDown(this TextBox tb, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Enter:
        case Keys.Add:
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            processTabKey(true);
            break;
        case Keys.Decimal:
            if (tb.Tag == "importe")
            {
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                processTabKey(true);
            }
            break;
        case Keys.Subtract:
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            processTabKey(false);
            break;
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs**

> This method calls the helper for moving to next element using ADD, SUBSTRACT, ENTER or DECIMAL keys. The helper is needed in order to use the same method for every form.

```
private void tb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TextBox).TextBoxKeyDown(e);
}
```

Comment: Show us the code, otherwise I am not really sure what you are trying to ask

Comment: Done @Habib that's the code I'm trying to use

Comment: This is unwise, these keys already have a use.  The Enter key operates the default button of the form.  On a multiline textbox it adds a new line.  The Decimal key will be used by many users that type a number.  As are the Add and Subtract keys to enter a sign.  Avoid making your UI mystifying to use.  And adding features that are completely undiscoverable.  Focus changes are already ably implemented by the cursor and tab keys, every user knows how to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the way to do it...
**MyClass.cs**

```
public static void TextBoxKeyDown(this TextBox tb, KeyEventArgs e, Control container)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Enter:
        case Keys.Add:
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            container.SelectNextControl(tb, true, true, false, true);
            //processTabKey(true);
            break;
        case Keys.Decimal:
            if (tb.Tag == "importe")
            {
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                container.SelectNextControl(tb, true, true, false, true);
            }
            break;
        case Keys.Subtract:
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            container.SelectNextControl(tb, false, true, false, true);
            break;
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
private void tb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TextBox).TextBoxKeyDown(e, this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by creating an instant but I can suggest a more proper way. You can create a class and put all methods you want to share in that class and then call that class from your forms. More effective way is to group methods and create different classes, so you dont have to implement all methods in all forms.